# Jwt with web services in java

Tags: jwt

I want to integrate jwt token in my spring service layer.I am passing a json object which should contain a token and I want to do authentication with that. How to do that . Thanks in advance

Comment: What approaches did you try already? Do you have any code parts where you struggle?

Comment: Hi GHajba, this is the dependency I have added 
                     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>      


Now I having a service which is being called and I want to put authentication on that can u please give me sample code so that I can try on it

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a solution for that . Instead of using spring-security-jwt usecom.nimbusdsnimbus-jose-jwt3.9And I am able to do the token authentication with this now.